# Product of 3 or more Spherical Harmonics

Tags: physics, spherical-harmonics

The product of two spherical harmonics can be written as the sum of spherical harmonics with coefficients related to Wigner 3j matrices ([ref eqn 16](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner3j-Symbol.html)) :

$$Y_{l_1m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{lm}W_{3j}(l_1,m_1,l_2,m_2,l,m)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)W_{3j}(l_1,0,l_2,0,l,0)$$

where $W_{3j}$ is the Wigner 3$j$ coefficient matrix.

I would like to generalize this to product of multiple spherical harmonics, an expression for :

$$\prod_{i=1}^N Y_{l_im_i}$$

Is there a nice expression for this? Or at least for $N=3$ and $N=4?$